# Button Added To DOM Not Clicking When Styles Are Applied (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm adding a dynamically created button to the DOM using jQuery, and applying styles to it, but when I click on the button, the click function does not work. Without the added styles, the click function works fine. Any suggestions for why this is happening, and how I can add a styled button to the DOM that will work with my click function?

```
   function createEditProfileButton() {
        return $('<button/>', {
        text: 'Edit Profile',
        id: 'btn_edit_profile',
        click: ClickEditProfile
    });
   }


 $('.footer').prepend(createEditProfileButton())
    function ClickEditProfile() {
    window.location = "https://some-link-here.com/edit";
    }


$("<style>").text("#btn_edit_profile {background: #3ba1da; vertical-align: middle !important; height: 44px; font-size: 15px; cursor: pointer !important; width: 200px; box-shadow: none; text-shadow: none; font-family: inherit; outline: none !important; margin: 0; opacity: 1; margin-left: 35%; margin-right: 1%; margin-top: -11%; text-decoration: none;}").appendTo("head");
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with that approach. When I don't add the '$("<style>").etc on the last line of my example, your suggestion works fine (and so does my original). I feel like the issue has something to do with how the DOM is loading my styles that I have added. If I delete the 'margin' for example, the button will click correctly.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry, `click` does seem to work like this. But this issue is not reproducable without some of your HTML. Right-click and Inspect Element. Your button is likely obscured by something else.

Comment: Okay, when I inspect the element, the focus in the DevTools takes me to a div higher up than where this element is currently located on the page... so I'm guessing ```('.footer').prepend``` may not be the right approach?

Comment: It depends on your HTML and your CSS. Without seeing a minimally complete version of your site that still reproduces the issue (see how to create a [mre]), it’s impossible to guess.